# Salt custom grains

Tags: python, salt-stack

I am trying to write custom grains.
I put this code in `/etc/salt/grains`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
def function():
    grains = {}
    grains['test'] = "test"
    return grains
```

and to test it I created this script:

```
import salt.config
import salt.loader
__opts__ = salt.config.minion_config('/etc/salt/minion')
__grains__ = salt.loader.grains(__opts__)
test = __grains__['test']
print test
```

I've got this error:

```
dirs = __grains__['test']
KeyError: 'test'
```

What's wrong with this ?

Comment: Where is `dirs` being assigned `__grains__['test']`.  I don't see the variable `dirs` anywhere in your provided code.  Maybe something is tripping you up elsewhere?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`/etc/salt/grains` is where salt stores grains set by `salt targetid grains.setval` and friends.  It is a flat, static yaml file.

Custom grains via python go in /srv/salt/_grains, and are then synced to minions with `salt \* saltutil.sync_grains`.  This is where you should put your python script.

Here is an example similar to your code with logging and verification:

```
$ cat /srv/salt/_grains/spam.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def function():
    log.trace('Setting grains["spam"] to "eggs"')
    grains = {}
    grains['spam'] = "eggs"
    return grains

$ sudo salt lead saltutil.sync_grains
lead:
    - grains.spam

$ sudo salt-call grains.item spam -l trace 2>&1 \
  | egrep '^local|spam'
[TRACE   ] Added spam.function to grain
[TRACE   ] Setting grains["spam"] to "eggs"
local:
  spam: eggs

$ cat /tmp/spam_taster.py 
#!/usr/bin/env python
import salt.config
import salt.loader
__opts__ = salt.config.minion_config('/etc/salt/minion')
__grains__ = salt.loader.grains(__opts__)
spam = __grains__['spam']
print spam

$ python /tmp/spam_taster.py 
eggs
```

Comment: Thanks, I've made it like this, I am still having the same error. I think the sync is not working.

Comment: I suspect your have other code somewhere that isn't provided here.  `dirs` isn't present in your examples. You can use the logger to help trace your code:
`import logging; log = logging.getLogger(__name__)` and then sprinkle `log.trace("Now in this part of code")` around your code.